# How can I send a socket event to backend from frontend with Sails JS?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to send a socket event from frontend to backend like so:

```
// frontend
this.io.socket.emit("something", { ...props });

// backend
sails.io.on("something", props => console.log(props));
```

However, it is not possible since there is no such event called `emit`. It is only `GET` or `POST` (like, wtf?) as you can see here: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client

I tried accessing `socket.io` in frontend but it is wrapped by `sails.io.js`.

Basically, I want to emit some events from frontend and I want backend to catch them. It's not a GET request to a controller, just an event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think sockets is the solution you need when you want to communicate **server -> client** (initiated by the server). If you want to send messages from **client -> server**, basically the whole rest of the internet is built to do that: send a simple `GET` or `POST`.

Are you maybe trying to initiate a socket connection from the front end? (so that the client can react to later server-initiated events?)

If you need to **trigger** a socket event on the back end, you should send a simple `GET` or `POST` then use code in the receiving controller to trigger the event using `emit` (and the emitted event will be received by all clients that have subscribed to the appropriate channel).